# How to add Xbox autherization scope in Microsoft App Registration

Tags: azure, xbox-live

I have a web app and i need to retrieve the Xbox Id of the user by signing in with a request URL which is : **https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?response_type=token&scope=service::user.auth.xboxlive.com::MBI_SSL&redirect_uri=https://localhost:44331/signin&client_id=MyClientId&display=touch&locale=en**

but when i run the URL i get a response back as : **https://localhost:44331/signin#error=invalid_scope&error_description=The+provided+value+for+the+input+parameter+scope+has+not+been+pre-authorized+for+this+client+application**

I have already register my localhost url in Microsoft app registration and it works perfectly fine with Microsft openId signin that i have in my other part of application. I tried to add the scope in app registration but i'm not sure if that's correct. I have added a screenshot of my app registration screen which show how i have added the scope. [image]

Comment: have you found the solution?

Comment: have you found the solution for authentication with xbox.